# Why do I not have permission to run this mpic command?

Tags: command-line, permissions, compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm very bad with the command line and have just downloaded Ubuntu (in the microsoft store) yesterday. I'm trying to compile and run a cpp file with a specific command. I'm logged in as a non-root user and this is the command I want to use to compile the file:

```
mpic++ circuitSatisfiability.cpp -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c++17 -o circuitSatisfiability
```

But then I get this message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file circuitSatisfiability: Permission denied
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mpic++: No such file or directory
```

If I do "ls" I can see my file is in there. Via the windows file I can also see that there is a ".idea" folder. Others could compile this way, why cant I?

Comment: If I write "mpic++" it tells me it doesn't have input files, so I guess it is accessible. Also, it did work if I used sudo. But people tell me I shouldn't use and shouldn't have to use this

Comment: You don't have write access to the current directory, that's why `ld` complains `cannot open output file `. Look at `ls -ld $PWD`.

Comment: I get this: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 21 16:35 /home/teemo/school